# Closing the iframe from javascript properly and by not hiding the iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I want to close an iframe... and i have used the code like making the iframe visible false or as display to none when i click on close btn... but that is effecting other codes in my project as the iframe is not closed and i am just hiding... and also that code works in Mozilla and Chrome fine this concept of hiding the iframe. But in IE this does not work at all... so i tried few other methods like... in the ifame page called this function on close btn click :

```
    function closeiframecommt() {
        parent.closeiframefriends();
    }
```

and in the page containing iframe i wrote code as:

```
function closeiframefriends() 
{
    var friends = document.getElementById("IFriends");
    friends.style.display = "none";
}
```

so... this works fine in Mozilla and Chrome but in IE... the first time i close the iframe it closes but the next time i try to open iframe it gives error and iframe does not open only... but this display none or visible false is effecting other code in project so i tried removechild code to close iframe again IE issue... so can u please help me with proper code to close iframe... as i tried finding code as when we click Esc or anywhere outside iframe it(iframe) closes properly so i want to know.. what happens when we press Esc or click outside iframe that iframe closes perfectly without effecting other codes.

Thanking You in advance!!

Comment: you cannot close an iframe :)

Answer (score 3):

you don't 'close' an iframe - you hide it or remove it. since hiding it is not an option for you - you should remove it. this works in both chrome and IE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .top {
        height:100px;
        width:200px;
        background-color:green;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function removeIFrame() {
        var frame = document.getElementById("target");
        frame.parentNode.removeChild(frame);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="top" onclick="removeIFrame();"></div>
    <iframe id="target" src="http://www.disney.com" width="100" height="100"></iframe>
    <div class="top"></div>
</body>
```

the onclick of the top green div handles removing the iframe from the DOM.

Comment: Hi... i just checked this... but it is not working in IE.. i am using IE8 .... so.. i tried including the breakpoint in javascript in Developer Tools of IE but that breakpoint it is not going there .. to know.. why it is not closing... PLease help!!

Comment: you would need to post an example of your page on jsfiddle.net or somewhere similiar. chances are that there is something else on your page that is broken.